# Magento2 how to prevent loading 10k products on category page?

Tags: magento2, category, category-products

our website is having 200000 products. One category is having 122000 products. 
when user load that category page it's fetching 10k products in one short(magento is limiting it to 10k instead of 122k products).

**How to change this 10k products limit to 500 products on that category page?**

Comment: Why your page is loading 10k products in the first place? I think this is the problem you need to fix.

Comment: RIP , the user that is using your website , how on earth is someone gonna browse through 122000 products, you should divide this category into subcategories and put products there.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 shows 10,000 Products in a category. If you have more than 10,000 products in your category then you have to change the size 
**search_request.xml file:**  **`<size>10000</size>`**

I have Created the custom module to override the **search_request.xml** file.
I have attached custom module [Download](https://github.com/hafizjee/Show-More-10k-Products-in-Frontend)